# How to run python file in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner in Python, hence the question.
i would like to run a python file (smileA.py) in Tkinter.
How would i start?

I do not wish for it to run when clicking a button, but the file to run automatically in the Tkinter itself.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Does your file `smileA.py` use tkinter? How do you run your Python files?

Comment: I run my python in the files itself.. smileA.py when run will be opened as a windows program. is it possible to instead open/display it in Tk?

Comment: Does your file smileA.py use tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

What you need  a module called *subprocess*, which will allow you to run files, from within your python code, by using Popen.

The code for running the file will look something like this, once you import the module:

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen("smileA.py")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

If that's what you mean by *"Running it in Tkinter"*, as in, running that code, while building a GUI in Tkinter in the same file.